# How do I list my app users in facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm trying to get all the users of my application. So far I found this method:

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = 1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user)
```

However this return *my friends who are using the app*. I want *all* users, whether they are my friends or not. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for security reasons. You have to log your app users but there are restrictions about this issue. You can check it out from: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Yeah, I kind of thought so. So I just made a Database instead, I didn't want to, but seems like that was the only option. Thank you